# NextJS: Context API for storing and passing values

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am building this project on NextJS where I want to build a shopping cart. For that, I decided to use useContext hook.
So basically what I did is pretty basic. Create a ShoppingCartContext, add a addToCart function which will push the data to store. But when I press the add to cart button it shows me that,

> store.push is not a function.

edit: When I press the button first time, nothing happens. When I press it the 2nd time it gives the mentioned error.
I think I did some basic stuff wrong in the code which is why I am getting this error.
My context code

```
import {
  createContext,
  useCallback,
  useContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
} from "react";

const ShoppingCartContext = createContext();

export function ShoppingCartContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [store, setStore] = useState([]);

  return (
    <ShoppingCartContext.Provider
      value={{
        store,
        setStore,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ShoppingCartContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useShoppingCartContext() {
  const { store, setStore } = useContext(ShoppingCartContext);

  //function to push data to array
  const addToCart = (product) => {
    setStore(store.push(product));
  };

  return {
    store,
    setStore,
    addToCart,
  };
}
```

Where I called the button component to add data

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useShoppingCartContext } from "../../context/CartContext";

const SingleProduct = ({ product, categories }) => {
  const { store, setStore, addToCart } = useShoppingCartContext();
  const router = useRouter();
  const breadcrumb = router.components["/shop/[[...category]]"].resolvedAs;

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
  const decrement = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
   
        <Button
              onClick={() => {
                addToCart(product); // product is basically an object which holds all the info of the single product
              }}
            >
              Add to Cart
            </Button>
    </>
   )
}
```

my _app.js file

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ShoppingCartContextProvider } from "../context/CartContext";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <ShoppingCartContextProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ShoppingCartContextProvider>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

please take a look at this.

Comment: Did you try to use let instead const when declaring store?

Comment: @LuisGar const/let doesn't matter. Still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For updating state which is array you need to do

```
setStore(store => [...store, product])

//OR 

// make clone of store and then setStore
temp=[...store]
temp.push(product)
setStore(temp)
```

**EXPLANATION OF CURRENT BEHAVIOUR**

1. In your case it's working 1st time as you have initialized `store` as `[]` empty array.
2. And because it's an array it has `.push()` method.
3. But `[].push(val)` will not return an array it will return the length of array.
4. And therefore after 1st time `store` get's the value of `numeric` datatype which does not has `.push()` method.

Below you can see the result of `.push()` your self.

```js
arr=[1,2,3] // length 3
console.log(`initial array`)
console.log(arr)
console.log(`spread operator + new val`)
console.log([...arr,5]) // spread operator + new val
console.log(`.push()`)
console.log(arr.push(5),"length=",arr.length) // .push() this will return length of the arr
```